# How do I show a selected option on two different identical webpages?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm pretty new to webpage and HTML, and I'm not sure what the easiest way to solve this program is. I have a basic webpage that I get data from a  tag, and then I have a button to push it to a part on the webpage.

**HTML**

```
<div id="footer">
   <p id="selectedEvent">Event</p>
</div>

<select id="currentEvent">
   <option value="" disabled selected>Current Event</option>
   <option value="1">Option 1</option>
   <option value="2">Option 2</option>
   <option value="3">Option 3</option>
</select>
<button type="button" onclick="GetSelectedText()">Push Changes</button>
```

**JS**

```
function GetSelectedText() {
   var e = document.getElementById("currentEvent");
   var result = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;
   document.getElementById("selectedEvent").innerHTML = result;
}
```

What I want this to do is update text on another instance of this code running in another tab, so that both webpages display the selected option after it is pushed on one of them. What's the easiest way to do this?

**EDIT**
I'm gonna briefly explain my use case just to get more useful responses. I'm using this as an overlay and interface for OBS as a browser source, so the solution needs to basically be able to sync across different browsers (ex Chrome and Firefox)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: do you mean browser tab?

Comment: Yes, I am running two different browser tabs with the same webpage through localhost.

Comment: @Sim I have added an answer. Please review it. If it works, please tell me so that I can add explanation to it.

Comment: Thanks, that works great, but not quite working for what I need. I should have explained my use case in the OP. I'm using this as an interface for a browser source overlay in OBS. I believe this solution doesn't work in my case because OBS is running its own internal browser to show that webpage and the local storage in chrome can't transfer over to the internal OBS browser that it uses to render the source. What's the easiest solution for this use case? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Sim have you tried it. Well, if it didn't work for you, I am sorry as I am not familiar with browser source overlay in OBS.

Comment: Yeah, I tried it and it does work as intended, I just need a solution that is equivalent to what your solution does, but in two different browsers (ex Chrome and Firefox), as I believe OBS works. If there isn't a solution you know of is there any guidance you can give to point me in the right direction?

Comment: @Sim, if you want to do this in tabs opened in two different browser, you must use some server scripting language like php. You can also use python (flask / django)

Comment: Thank you for your assistance, I will look into that.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want?

```
var e = document.getElementById("currentEvent");

function GetSelectedText() {
    var selected = e.options[e.selectedIndex];
    document.getElementById("selectedEvent").innerHTML = selected.text;

    if (typeof(Storage) !== "undefined") { 
        localStorage.setItem("s_option", selected.text);
        localStorage.setItem("s_option_value", selected.value);
    }
}

function show_result() {
    document.getElementById("selectedEvent").innerHTML = localStorage.getItem("s_option");
    document.getElementById("currentEvent").value = localStorage.getItem("s_option_value");
}

window.addEventListener("storage", show_result);
e.addEventListener("change", GetSelectedText);
```